# How to properly group mongodb results to reduce the dataset in java with morphia 0.99

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I am on a project that uses the old morphia 0.99 in a Maven Spring MVC application, with no realistic option to upgrade to the latest supported versions.

I am attempting to search a very large (63 million document) collection to validate identifiers that a user has uploaded via a CSV document. The goal is to associate a given id with an agnt_id. The documents are something like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53430e789f0b37b71976d2f1"),
  "agnt_id" : 1234,
  "a" : 793,
  "b" : "D2QT",
  "c" : "85B56",
  "d" : 119,
  "e" : "comm",
  "f" : "2C27",
  "g" : "DE00Z29UU3",
  "h" : "",
  "i" : "DE00M83DH1",
  "j" : 13211
}
```

I am currently using 
`Query<IdentifierVO> query = ds.createQuery(IdentifierVO.class).field(propertyName).in(identifiers).
retrievedFields(true, propertyName, "agnt_id");`

to return results, but this often results in over 100,000 documents being returned, which is a major network cost and much more inefficient than I'm comfortable with.

I am attempting to execute this following command, which returns me exactly what I need without all the extra documents, but I am unable to make this work:

```
db.runCommand({
  group: {
    ns: 'id_search',
    key: {
        agnt_id: 1,
        g: 1
    },
    cond: {
        g: {
            $in: [
                32008,
                11989
            ]
        }
    },
    $reduce: function(curr,
    result){

    },
    initial: {

    }
   }
})
```

But my two attempts fail with errors: (rawQuery = the command text above)

`Object result = ds.getDB().authenticate("mongousr", password); //password is char[]. Auth returns true`

`Object result2 = ds.getDB().eval(rawQuery);`

results in :

`22:55:20,215 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/clientportal].[appServlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "redacted" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "unauthorized"}`

Is there anyway to get mongodb to run the command I want, or is there another way to group the data to reduce the dataset being transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not be using this method, it is actually just a wrapper around [**`mapReduce`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) and therefore runs arbitrary JavaScript through an interpreter which is not very efficient.

What you need is the [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method. A basic shell example:

```js
 db.collection.aggregate([
     { "$match": {
         "g": "$in": [ 32008, 11989 ]
     }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
             "agnt_id": "$agnt_id",
             "g": "$g"
         }
    }}
 ])
```

You should have access to the actual aggregate command with resorting to using the "runCommand" method. It should be under standard "read" methods in terms of access.

Or actually from morphia you should be able to work of a Datastore instance in order to get the [raw collection](https://rawgit.com/wiki/mongodb/morphia/javadoc/0.107/apidocs/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#getCollection%28java.lang.Class%29) as implemented in the driver. So something like:

```
    // get collection
    DBCollection collection = ds.getCollection("collection");

    // Arguments
    BasicDBList myargs = new BasicDBList();
    myargs.add(new Integer(32008));
    myargs.add(new Integer(11989));

    // $match phase
    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
        new BasicDBObject("g",
            new BasicDBObject("$in", myargs)
        )
    );

    // $group phase
    BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group",
        new BasicDBObject("_id",
            new BasicDBObject("agnt_id","$agnt_id")
                .append("g", "$g")
        )
    );

    // pipeline
    BasicDBList pipeline = new BasicDBList();
    pipeline.add(match);
    pipeline.add(group);

    // Aggregate
    AggregationOutput output =  collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

There are some other builder options available that makes the process nicer if you are fine with mixing dependencies, but this gives the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From what I can find, the aggregation framework is not supported in morphia 0.99, nor the Mongodb driver version 2.11.x, as it is to be added in to 2.12: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases. As I stated, upgrading morphia versions is not an option :-(

Comment: @dev_row Yes it is. You just need to access the underlying [collection](https://rawgithub.com/wiki/mongodb/morphia/javadoc/0.107/apidocs/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#getCollection) object from the underlying Java Driver where the aggregate method is supported. Or even use the [dbCommand interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/), everything is actuall just a dbCommand anyway.

Comment: And why is the aggregate dbcommand more ideal for usage here than the group dbcommand as per my own answer below? I'm happy to change my method, I just don't understand the reason I would do so.

Comment: @dev_row Simply put, switching into something that is actually "interpreting" JavaScript into a native environment is always going to run **much** slower than anything that is actually already native code, due to the general tokenizing and interpretation that is required (and a very broad subject). But really the **agregation framework** was introduced after the initial and simple inclusion of the JavaScript methods such as "mapReduce" and are (and will continue to be) far more optimized than the original methods. The **group** command is just a basic wrapper on mapReduce.

Comment: Thank you. For more reading for others who see this, see a performance test here http://blog.mongodb.org/post/62900213496/qaing-new-code-with-mms-map-reduce-vs-aggregation and Mongo's comparison of the aggregation features here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-commands-comparison/

Comment: @dev_row I am very much aware of the performance differences are spend some time doing benchmarks and stress tests over the code base myself. Perhaps you might consider changing your accepted solution then :)

Comment: The links were for other readers. If you provide me a working solution I'd be happy to mark this answer accepted, as this is a better approach. As is, I am unable to use this, even if it may seem trivial to implement to those who have more morphia and java experience.

Comment: @dev_row Reasonable, I have included the process of accessing an underlying collection from the Datastore and constructing a basic aggregation statement from the Java driver Basic objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I needed:

First of all "eval" is the wrong method to use. This runs javascript on the server, and is not what I needed for my purposes. I instead constructed a DBObject and ran the command this way. The working code is below, where identifiers is a Set, and propertyName is a string

```
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject groupparams = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject key = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject cond = new BasicDBObject();
    DBObject in = new BasicDBObject();

    groupparams.put("ns", "port_identifiers");
    key.put("agnt_id", 1);
    key.put(propertyName, 1);
    groupparams.put("key", key);

    in.put("$in", identifiers);
    cond.put(propertyName, in);
    groupparams.put("cond", cond);

    groupparams.put("$reduce", "function(curr, result) {}");
    groupparams.put("initial", new BasicDBObject());

    group.put("group", groupparams);

    CommandResult result = ds.getDB().command(group);
```

produces something like::

`{ "group" : { "ns" : "id_search" , "key" : { "agnt_id" : 1 , "z" : 1} , "cond" : { "acid" : { "$in" : [ 7943 , 11330]}} , "$reduce" : "function(curr, result) {}" , "initial" : { }}}`

and returns:

`{ "serverUsed" : "redacted" , "retval" : [ { "agnt_id" : 111464.0 , "z" : 7943.0} , { "agnt_id" : 111466.0 , "z" : 11330.0}] , "count" : 112034.0 , "keys" : 2 , "ok" : 1.0}`

Comment: Note that while this solution gives the desired results, it is very inefficient. See above and implement the chosen answer if possible.